# How to center the Flow widget within the ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I'm currently facing an issue with centering a **`Flow`** widget within a **`ConstraintLayout`**. The **`Flow`** widget contains two child **`TextView`** elements, and I want the entire **`Flow`** to be centered both horizontally and vertically within the **`ConstraintLayout`**. Despite using constraints, the widget doesn't appear to be centered as expected. I've tried adjusting the constraints and attributes, but the issue persists. Can anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to correctly center the **`Flow`** widget within the **`ConstraintLayout`**?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_password">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_submit"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_purple_corner"
        android:fontFamily="@font/inter_regular"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/_10dp"
        android:text="Update"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_cancel"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_black_corner"
        android:fontFamily="@font/inter_regular"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/_10dp"
        android:text="My Sales"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/cl_ac_re"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/_20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cd_otheritem">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
                android:id="@+id/flow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:constraint_referenced_ids="text_view_accept,text_view_reject"
                app:flow_horizontalGap="@dimen/_10dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_accept"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_rounded_10"
                android:fontFamily="@font/inter_regular"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingVertical="@dimen/_10dp"
                android:text="@string/accept"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_reject"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_rounded_10"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/_393F48"
                android:fontFamily="@font/inter_regular"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/reject"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12sp" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this layout creates a row of two buttons with rounded corners (text_view_accept and text_view_reject) inside a ConstraintLayout. The Flow widget helps in horizontally arranging the buttons, and each button is individually styled with specific dimensions, background, and text properties.